# Creating dynamic class in a PHP foreach loop that a jQuery function can access

Tags: php, jquery, html, foreach

I have a problem which is proving to be difficult. I have a forum with multiple responses to a question, being pulled from a database and displayed using a foreach loop (PHP). I want an 'edit your response' function and have a jquery function which will 'show' a block of HTML which includes and input underneath each response. The problem is, when I select the edit button on one response it acitvates the bloack of HRML under every response because its targetting the class 'theDiv'. Is it possible to have a jquery function that can select just one.......i.e.somehow have each response in the foreach loop have a dynamically created unique class that a jquery function can target? Really struggling to see how this can be done.....

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .theDiv{
      display:none;
     }
    </style>

    <link href="styles/threads_page.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".show").click(function() {
            $(".theDiv").show("normal");
        });
        $(".hide").click(function() {
            $(".theDiv").hide("normal");
         });
      });
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <?php foreach($responses as $response):?>
    <h3><?php echo $response->author . "<br/>"; 
      echo $response->content;                   
      echo "<div class=\"theDiv\">
          <form action=\"question_gallery.php\" method=\"post\" class=\"form\">
          <table>
           <tr> 
                 <td>      
                    Edit your response:         
                       <input class=\"question_field\" name=\"question\"/>
                  </td>
           </tr>
          </table>                
       </form>
         </div>
       <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
               <button class=\"show\">Edit response</button>
          </td>
         <td>
           <button class=\"hide\">Close</button>
        </td>
       </tr> 
      </table>  
     ";} ?> 
  <?php endforeach; ?>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Use `$(this)` to target just the element that was clicked on.

Comment: Start with `this`, traverse the DOM to the element you want. http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traverse the DOM starting from `$(this)`:

```
$(function() {
    $(".show").click(function() {
        $(this).closest("table").prev(".theDiv").show("normal");
    });
    $(".hide").click(function() {
        $(this).closest("table").prev(".theDiv").hide("normal");
     });
});
```

`(this)` is the element that you clicked on. `.closest("table")` searches up the DOM hierarchy to the containing `<table>` element. `.prev(".theDiv")` selects the element immediately before it, as long as it has `class="theDiv"`. This works for your HTML because the table and div are in sequential pairs.

Comment: Barmar and all, many thanks. I'm a complete newbie with jquery. Could you explain your answer just a little more...would I use the exact code you have quoted above? Thanks again

Comment: Added some explanation. But if you expect to make it as a programmer, you need to learn how to read and understand documentation. You can't expect people to spoon-feed you everything. This has nothing to do with being a jquery newbie, it's just a necessary skill for a programmer.

Comment: Thanks a million. Will try this in a few hours and let you know. Awesome

Comment: Agreed. I'm a doctor with 6 months coding experience....your help is well taken. Many thanks

Comment: Barmar.....just wanted to say thanks. This works perfectly and has given me new area to study...traversing the DOM. I just needed to be steered in the right direction. Awesome.